# How do I fix at least one of my attempts to reference a label in a file in another folder?

Tags: cross-referencing

I am unsuccessful in trying to follow instruction to do a `\ref` to a `\label` in a different file. Ultimately, this will be for a file in a different folder; I have one folder for Installation Guide files and another folder for System Administration Guide files.

I tried two different methods, described in (1) and (2) below. My code is in (3) and (4).

(1) Result of attempt using `\input{../TestFolder/outiedoc.aux}`:
The chapter number is properly inserted. However, extra garbage in italics appears: "writefiletoc" and "writefilelofwritefilelot". Should I expect those to disappear once I use the command in a real document rather than a little test file?

(2) Result of using

```
\usepackage{xr}
\externaldocument{../Testfolder/outiedoc} :
```

No garbage, but I get ?? instead of the chapter number.

(3) This is what I have in outiedoc:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{The Far Shore}\label{ch:outieRef}
    This is the first chapter of the book.
\end{document}
```

(4) This is what I have in the calling document, aside from alternating between the lines in (1) and (2) above:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
    You can find what you are looking for in chapter~\ref{ch:outieRef} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @egreg! I have been welcomed with grace...the person who answered my first question also edited the question itself to remedy its total lack of formatting. Now I am learning how to format correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `\usepackage{xr}` and `\externaldocument{outiedoc}` in your calling document, say, `maindoc.tex`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xr}
\externaldocument{outiedoc}

\begin{document}
    You can find what you are looking for in chapter~\ref{ch:outieRef} 
\end{document}
```

And in `outiedoc.tex`

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{The Far Shore}\label{ch:outieRef}
    This is the first chapter of the book.
\end{document}
```

Please compile both files twice, preferably `outiedoc.tex` first, then `maindoc.tex`.

Comment: I've omitted a screenshot for simplicity

Comment: Thank you! It was an understanding of the compiling that I was lacking.

Comment: @AudreyFisher: Happy TeXing ;-)